# How to let http web browsers run simultaneously in inet (omnet++)

Tags: simulation, omnet++, inet

I developed the following network and it runs perfectly all what I need from it I get it..

.ini

[image]

attached is the graphical visualization:
[image: sim.png]

What remains is that I need  to let the web browsers located in the hosts to generate  traffic simultaneously (means that for example I want to see host [6] and host[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYYQf.png) sending to the servers at the same time and so)
I need this because I want to capture traffic at the link layer level based on specific statistics. The current situation doesn't produce the statistics I want to generate.

The current simulation runs as follows:
[image: sim2.png]
The connection between a  host and a server has to finish then the next communication session between another host and a server will start. It seems like that.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you absolutely sure that they cannot run at the same time? Simulation time and animation time is two completely different thing. i.e. even if you see that message animations of two messages are sequentially animated on the GUI, it does NOT mean that they are not happening in the same time in simulation time.

Watch the simulation time in the upper right corner and see when it is progressing and when not. Or (if you are more of a visual type) record an event log from the simulation and see the sequence chart generated from that run. You will easily see events that are happening at the same simulation time.

Comment: Thank you for the insights. Yes the simulation time bar shows changes in fractions of seconds.